# Executing HTTP requests from native code

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have to make HTTP calls from native code (GET and POST requests). Can some one shed some light on this ? I'm not looking for generic JNI solution, I'm looking more like reference implementation particularly for HTTP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had successfully run libcurl to Android 8. You can surf the net and search for resource:

[for instance](http://thesoftwarerogue.blogspot.it/2010/05/porting-of-libcurl-to-android-os-using.html)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Blackbelt, Though I am tempted to do this, I needed quick JNI based solution, however thums up for this answer, I will wait for a couple of days for some one else to give some quick solution

Answer (score 2):

I had similar requirements for building an engine on android. I successfully tried and ported both libcurl and libsoup.

I would say libcurl is far more stable and better documented.

Comment: I think I need to download complete android source and build libcurl as suggested in posts, I would rather want some quick JNI implementation or Can I find libcurl binaries somewhere?